# FOC Iq peak current overshoot

Tags: motor

I have a FOC controller for a servo motor, where the Iq current can overshoot the maximum allowed Iq current (That is the reference value limit for Iq) by around 80-100% under heavy dynamic load.

When I use the servo motor with a constant attached load and give position or velocity commands, the Iq current does never overshoot more than around 5%, also when I go for example from full speed 3000rpm to -3000rpm.

In the used application however, the load changes dynamically, such that the servo first is fully in generator mode, then goes fully in motor mode and then suddenly with full force again into generator mode. The change from the motor mode into the generator mode leads to the overshoot of around 80-100% as seen in the following graphs.

My PI current controller is automatically tuned, by using the phase resistance and inductance to achieve a linear plant of the motor and then the bandwidth is chosen, such that the motor runs smooth enough. When I actually increase the bandwidth, the overshoot is less, but the noise of the motor increases.

So my questions are:

- Is this a normal behaviour or may there be something wrong?
- As you can see in the second picture, the iq integrator sum increases in the motor mode of the servo and when suddenly the load change appears and the servo goes into the generator mode, the overshoot occurs as long as the integrator needs to adjust the value.
- How fast is normally an integrator in the current loop? In our controller, the delay from 20V to 0V seems to be around 150ms at that seems to be the reason for the overshoot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: is the controller a 4-quadrant controller?  if it is then this is a loop-tuning problem. While there will be a bit of an overshoot as the loop gain doubles at the switch point, your controller should have high enough bandwidth to cope with this.

Comment: It depends on moment of inertia....@JonRB wouldn’t it?

Comment: Yes it is a 4-quadrant controller. The thing is, under normal inertia (motor is coupled to a disk over a belt and pulley) the load changes do not overshoot, also when I immediately switch from 3000rpm to -3000rpm, in this case the motor has generator and motor modes. But the peaks occur only, when the motor is in the motor mode and suddendly a load is coupled into the spinning disk in the opposit direction

Comment: @TonyStewart, the current loop is purely dependant on the DC link and the RL. The inertia will influence how much energy needs to be extracted and also the velocity loop gains

Comment: “in theory, there’s no difference between theory and practice, but in practise , there is”. What is the difference in overshoot with step size in a dynamic bipolar load? Is the step size vs overshoot proportional or just with load direction changes gets worse or ??  . The damping factor may be dependent on more than 2 variables. Torque reduction from saturation?? Is it close to V/DCR? Probably not. So again, what are your acceptance criteria, and what have you tried? Max torque from 0 RPM is V/DCR may be tolerable but unlikely at full RPM reverse. These are under your control. Flywheel=nogo

Comment: Do you have some means to regulate the DC voltage? When you decelerate and the rotor energy is transferred to the DClink capacitor, this will increase unless there is some means to regulate this. If you have a Butterworth response on you current look this can easily result in a significantly underdamped response when the voltage goes up significantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately PI cannot predict the dynamic change reversal in force that switches it from generator to motor mode and you need to incorporate Differential gain, Kd, to anticipate the change to reduce overshoot.  Changes to PI gain may also be necessary slightly as Ki gain stores some history according to it’s time constant.

The surge current will be proportional to the tradeoff allowed for speed error and current overshoot as RPM load regulation depends on the ratio of load torque to available counter motor-torque.  If you specify your permitted load regulation error in RPM and current overshoot, you may be able to meet spec. But these are trade offs.

The grid operates the same way to load changes but at a much slower rate of change in RPM or Hz in order to maintain voltage regulation with field current at the new demand power levels within 5% V and 5% f slowly changing (estimated not from grid specs). These trade offs are determined by design of excess capacity. In areas with excess power capacity, in isolation, RPM can be caesium clock synchronized , which was the case in Winnipeg during the late 70’s when I verified with 1e-10 frequency counters for 60Hz. Thus is just an analogy to your problem.

Comment: Yes, the differentiator is a solution, but i have never seen anyone use the D-part for the current loop in FOC? Also every paper has no D-part in the current loop. So maybe there is something else missing here...

Comment: Or something they are missing like your overcurrent and dynamic load swings.trust me... but if you have a sensor from speed control or load shift , you might be able to reduce Kp significantly during this interval or do it in software... which is basically the same thing as Kd

Comment: But I see your Iq Integral is too high for Ki, again it comes down to speed or phase change in motor with time vs current specs. Is the motor/gen sync’d to the grid? What causes the load swings? Would a flywheel help? Which is a mechanical equivalent to reducing Ki

Comment: The motor is driven by a 48VDC power supply and not used with the grid

Comment: Ok so what are your specs for I and RPM? What is the sensitivity of Ki to your overshoot?

Comment: Iq should peak less than 10%, the motor can go at max. 3000rpm. I did not calculate the sensitivity of Ki so far, it seems it takes around 150ms to go from 20V to 0V as seen above. How fast should the integrator be normally for FOC in the current loop?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your motor's torque characteristic and your system inertia, I'm betting that your system response is "normal."  An FOC design is dependent on the relationship between current and torque, but a motor can physically only supply a finite amount of torque no matter how much current is supplied.  The fact that you can change your motor's speed smoothly under load probably means that your system has chosen good PI values for the motor/inertial load combination when in the motor's normal current/torque range.  Your problem may be that when you apply rapid, high amplitude changes to the torque load, that the motor may be unable to supply sufficient instantaneous torque to counteract these changes within a current range in which the motor torque constant applies.  Instead, the motor is driven to a range outside of the region where the linear torque vs. current relationship holds.  Then when the controller "catches up," the response is higher than theoretical, and the PI loop has to traverse back into the motor's normal current range.  Because the response value is higher than it should be (out of the range), the initial change in response does not have the desired theoretical effect, and the PI loop falls behind so that overshoot occurs.  If this is your issue, you won't be able to completely eliminate this problem with the K values.

Good luck!

Comment: That seems reasonable, thank you, but I have another idea what could cause the problem, as seen from the integrator output from the second picture in my post: When the motor is in the motor mode, it want to apply the maximum current, but at the higher speed, it cannot regulate the current perfectly to the reference value through the small and rapid load changes on the way, so the integrator increases to the maximum value possible. Now the integrator is fully loaded when it changes back to the generator mode and needs to unload, so the peak. What do you think about this?

Comment: Excellent point; this is a good possibility especially if you have plenty of motor.  In either case, your problem is the same - the loop only works properly when all of the components are in a range where they act in a linear fashion.